# How to restore default xib values each time after returning back from another view?

Tags: xcode, xib, default-value

I'm using a xib in xCode4 which is a table filled largely with static, default values. (These values were manually set in IB and are typically dashes to show empty cells.)  The user enters input parameters on a preceding view, a bunch of calculations happen, and some of the default values on the xib on then updated.

My question is, when the user goes back to change the input parameters, new calculations are done on different values, and the xib is viewed a second (or third, etc.) time, how can I restore all the default values before updating some of them with calculated values? Otherwise I have to programmatically set either the default or the calculated value for each variable.

Thanks for the help.